# Opencart Checkout Registration Issue

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

Hello i am using opencart 2.x version. During checkout if i am selecting "Register Account" option then on next window after registration it will redirecting us to the thankyou page. Can anyone tell me how can i disable this so that user will remain on checkout page.

Comment: You need to write a modification for that to unset session variables which are done in the thank you page controller. Then add a javascript snippet to prevent redirecting to the thank you page.

Comment: Ok Thanks Scott. I will check the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default OpenCart, doesn't redirect you to thank you for your registration page. It will ask the user for all details and password so it will create a customer registration and get a customer_id for that particular order. So if you see thank you page after checkout it's either thank you for your order page, or you have custom code / other extensions installed.

Comment: Yes you may be right. Because i just saw some other setup of Opencart and found there is no redirection.